# Store condition test in variable

Tags: xslt

I am **quite new** to XSLT and need to transform an address xml file. 
I need to store the result of an condition test in a variable, I want to use it later in the same template.

Here my source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message>
<partner>
    <addressInfo>
        <addressUsage>
            <Code>Default</Code>
            <Main>false</Main>
        </addressUsage>
        <addressUsage>
            <Code>BILL_TO</Code>
            <Main>false</Main>
        </addressUsage>
        <Address>...</Address>
    </addressInfo>
    <addressInfo>
        <addressUsage>
            <Code>SHIP_TO</Code>
            <Main>false</Main>
        </addressUsage>
        <addressUsage>
            <Code>BILL_TO</Code>
            <Main>true</Main>
        </addressUsage>
        <Address>...</Address>
    </addressInfo>
</partner>
</message>
```

Now, I need to know if there is an address with code "BILL_TO" and Main = "true". I need to store this in a variable. But in my test I always fail.

Here my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<!-- copy all nodes and attributes -->  
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="partner">
    <partner>
    <xsl:variable name="main_bill_to">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="(./addressInfo/addressUsage/Code = 'BILL_TO' and Main = 'true')">
                <xsl:value-of select="'Y'" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="'N'" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable> 

    <xsl:if test="($main_bill_to = 'Y')">
        <result>yes</result>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="($main_bill_to = 'N')">
        <result>no</result>
    </xsl:if>
    </partner>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I always get the output "no".

```
<message>
    <partner>
       <result>no</result>
    </partner>
</message>
```

Any idea? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This expression is not quite right...

```
<xsl:when test="(./addressInfo/addressUsage/Code = 'BILL_TO' and Main = 'true')">
```

You are actually asking "*Is there an element `addressInfo/addressUsage/Code` (under `partner`) equal to 'BILL_TO', and is there also an element `Main` (under `partner`) equal to 'true'*".

In other words, it is looking for an element named `Main` under `partner`, not under the same `addressUsage` as the `Code` element you are checking.

You need to do this...

```
<xsl:when test="addressInfo/addressUsage[Code = 'BILL_TO' and Main = 'true']">
```

So, this is now asking "*Is there an `addressInfo/addressUsage` element which has both `Code` set to 'BILL_TO' and `Main` set to 'true'*"?

Note the `./` is not really necessary, which is why I removed it.

Also note, you don't really need to go to all the trouble of using an `xsl:choose` to set the variable to "Y" or "N". You can, in this case, simplify the code block to this....

```
<xsl:template match="partner">
  <partner>
    <xsl:variable name="main_bill_to" select="addressInfo/addressUsage[Code = 'BILL_TO' and Main = 'true']" />

    <xsl:if test="$main_bill_to">
        <result>yes</result>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="not($main_bill_to)">
        <result>no</result>
    </xsl:if>
  </partner>
</xsl:template>
```

So now, you are checking if an element exists to determine what to display.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved!